# Open .NETCore Yeoman generated projects in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio Preview (Mac)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, xamarin-studio, yeoman-generator

I've generated a .NETCore project using the Yeoman CLI tool on my Mac. I'm able to run the project using Visual Studio Code. However I want to be able to open and run the project with either Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio Preview. Is this possible? Both IDEs seem to require an .sln file, however the Yeoman generated project doesn't provide one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be correct, both IDEs supports `.csproj` file, not `project.json`, that was [announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/) with latest .NET Core Tools. What you may try to do is to migrate your project.json using the `dotnet migrate` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-migrate):

> dotnet-migrate -- Migrates a Preview 2 .NET Core project to Preview 3 .NET Core project

Comment: Thanks! That worked for "Web API Application" projects generated with Yeoman. However it seems that Visual Studio Preview doesn't support Yeoman generated "Web Application" projects. From what I can gather, Visual Studio Preview only supports backend .NETCore projects - so nothing with a UI attached. I'll have to use Visual Studio Code for them